# magrittr tee pipe %T>% equivalent

Tags: r, tidyverse, magrittr

I'm looking at the example of the magrittr tee pipe %T>% in the documentation, but I'm not immediately grasping what it's doing. Can someone show what the equivalent code is without the tee pipe?

```
rnorm(200) %>%
matrix(ncol = 2) %T>%
plot %>% # plot usually does not return anything. 
colSums
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`%T>%` is presumably named after the T-shaped pipe splitter used in plumbing.

[image: T splitter]

We can replace `%T>%` with `%>%` if we replace the `plot` line in the question with the `plot` line shown below (and marked with a double hash).  This plots its input and then forwards the input to the output so that the pipeline can be continued.

```
rnorm(200) %>%
  matrix(ncol = 2) %>%
  { plot(.); . } %>%    ##
  colSums
```

Thus the processing follows this graph:

```
rnorm --> matrix --T--> colSums
                   |
                   v
                  plot
```

Answer (score 3):

We can wrap it in a `{}` to get the equivalent output

```
library(dplyr)
rnorm(200) %>%
   matrix(ncol = 2)  %>% 
      { plot(.)
       colSums(.)
    }
```

NOTE: This was posted first with the `{}`